# How can I fix my for loop in a javascript quiz?

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop, nested-loops

I'm making a javascript quiz using a single HTML page. For some reason, my code will only display one question and upon clicking the element, it does not go to the next question. And it doesn't start the quiz with the first question.

I used a `for` loop inside a `for` loop. The first loop renders the question and then the other renders its corresponding choices. The questions and choices are held in an array containing the objects.

I've only been coding with Javascript and jQuery for a few weeks, so you'll have to tell me in beginner terms. I will have to refactor it. I apologize for it being somewhat messy.

I tried taking out the `return` commands. Same with `preventDefault`, no changes.

```js
function renderQuiz(i) {
  $heading.text("");
  $mainDiv.text("");
  $heading.text(quizQuestions[i].question);

  for (var j = 0; j < quizQuestions[i].choices.length; j++) {
    //console.log(quizQuestions[0].choices.length);
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    li.innerText = JSON.stringify(quizQuestions[i].choices[j]);
    $mainDiv.append(li);
  };

  $('li').on("click", function() {
    if (event.target.matches('li')) {
      event.preventDefault();
      var guess = event.target.innerText;
      var answer = (JSON.stringify(quizQuestions[i].answer[0]));
      if (guess === answer) {
        timeLeft += 10;
        console.log(timeLeft + "it works");
      } else {
        timeLeft -= 10;
        console.log(timeLeft)
      };
    }
  });
  return;
};

mainPage();

$button.on("click", function(click) {
  event.preventDefault();
  for (var i = 0; i < quizQuestions.length; i++) {
    renderQuiz(i);;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The $button click event is iterating through all of the questions, that is why the last question is the one displayed.

You need to define the variable i outside of the $button click function, then increment i on each click of the button.

```js
var i = -1;

function renderQuiz(i) {
  ...
};

mainPage();

$button.on("click", function(click) {
  event.preventDefault();
  renderQuiz(++i);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an error in the $button onclick handler (in your console you should have "Uncaught ReferenceError: event is not defined").

If the function takes *click* as parameter then you should apply the method preventDefault() to that same parameter. In other words instead of

```
$button.on("click", function(click) {
  event.preventDefault();
```

you should have

```
$button.on("click", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
```

By the way there is the same error here

```
$('li').on("click", function() {
```

you should have

```
$('li').on("click", function(event) {
```

I hope this help.